# css mobile submenu won't expand on click

Tags: css

I have a mobile menu with one submenu at http://plushdesign.net/plush5/contact/. For some reason, it has stopped expanding on click in mobile (on all pages of the site--I am using this page bc it doesn't have any js).

The basic html (trimmed for simplicity) is:

```
<ul id="primary-main-menu" class="menu" style="display: block;">
<li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
<li id="menu-item-1901" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1901 hover">
    <a class="parent" href="http://plushdesign.net/plush5/work/">Work</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-2105" class="hide menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2105">
        <li id="menu-item-2104" class="hide menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2104">
        </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

the relevant css is:

```
#primary-main-menu li.hide, 
ul#primary-main-menu.menu li.hover ul.sub-menu li.hide {
    visibility: visible;
}

#primary-main-menu > li.hover > ul, 
#primary-main-menu li li.hover > ul, 
#primary-main-menu li:hover ul, 
#primary-main-menu li.hover a ul {
    display: block !important;
    position: static !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

I have looked everywhere and tried every combination of selectors I can think of, and cant find why it stopped dropping down...can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel look again

Comment: @SebastienDaniel agree with @Aziz, there are classes called `.hover` there's no state.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `li`s inside submenu ul have `display:none`, you'd have to enable them with `#primary-main-menu li ul li { display: block !important }`. I have never seen so many `!important` rules since a long time...

Comment: Comment #1: not helpful.

Comment: Comment #3: yes, there are a lot of importants...some I needed to override the parent theme (who uses them); others are left over from development and will be cleaned up once everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is a problem in your `mobile-menu.js` that is not toggling the classes `hide` in the `li` items inside `.sub-menu`, when clicking the `.parent`. It suppose to be synced with the `.hover` class toggled in `.menu-item` when clicking.

Try remove manually the class `hide` in each sub item from the browser inspector and it works.

Something like

```
$("#primary-main-menu li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').find('li').toggleClass("hide") // <<< line added
});
```

Comment: I removed the hide class all together and will reformat on the desktop site accordingly. from here I was able to get it to work. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get onclick submenu you need to use javascript/jquery. Here is the demo. Quick and easy.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#trigger').click(function(){
  $('#hide').toggleClass('expand')
   })
 })
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/21p6xm9g/2/)